# Entity Framework - Create navigation property

Tags: c#, sql, visual-studio, entity-framework

i created a db-model with the entity framework wizzard in Visual Studio. There are 2 tables (job, stocktype) which are related to each other with the table stocktype2job.

[image]

```
Job <------- no direct relation / navigation property --------> StockType
 |                                                                  |
 |                                                                  |
 ---------------------> StockType2Job ----------------------------->
```

With a Job Object, i could do something like this ...

```
EntitiesObject db = new EntitiesObject();
Job job = db.Jobs.SingleOrDefault(j => j.IdJob == 40);

List<StockType> stockTypes = new List<StockType>;
foreach (StockType2Job st2j in job.StockType2Jobs)
    {
        stockTypes.add(st2j.StockType);
    }
```

That should work just fine. But is there a way to create a navigation property in the job entity so i can write something like this?

```
EntitiesObject db = new EntitiesObject();
Job job = db.Jobs.SingleOrDefault(j => j.IdJob == 40);

List<StockType> stockTypes = job.StockTypes; // <<-----
```

Thanks for your kind Help
Apo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is clear (from the self reference) that `StockType2Jobs` does not only contain foreign keys to StockType and Job, so you can't map a many-many relationship with a navigation property `job.StockTypes`. So you can't do anything else then collecting `StockType` via `job.StockType2Jobs`. But that's not a big deal:

```
List<StockType> stockTypes = job.StockType2Jobs.Select(x => x.StockType);
```

You might get tempted to wrap this in an unmapped property `job.StockTypes`, but usually it's not a good idea to do this.

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this:

```
 var stocksTypes = from st in db.StockType 
     from stj in st.StockType2Job where stj.Job.IdJob==40 select st;
```

- This code is not creating any new navigation property, it just "joining" the tables. I supose that the StockType2Jobs table exists for a good reason.

I recommend you to have a look at how to deal with N to N relationship with EF.

Some links [[1]](http://weblogs.asp.net/zeeshanhirani/archive/2008/08/21/many-to-many-mappings-in-entity-framework.aspx) [[2]](http://smehrozalam.wordpress.com/2010/06/29/entity-framework-queries-involving-many-to-many-relationship-tables/)

Hope Helps

Comment: no doubt that this would work but i rather dont want to use linq when there is a more elegant way, but thx anyway!